# Selenium IDE command for input type hidden

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

am new to selenium and while recording in selenium IDE it is not recording drop - down list am posting html code of it.

If the IDE is not recording the event, issue such as the element being defined as hidden.

Thanks for your help :)

```
<input type="hidden" name="roleSpecification.industries.id" value="" />
<select name="roleSpecification.industries.id" size="3" data-placeholder="Any"   class="test chzn-select" multiple="multiple" id="roleSpecification_industries_id" >
<option value="1">Accounting</option>
<option value="2">Architecture &amp; Planning</option>
<option value="3">Arts</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.9/firebug-1.9.0.xpi) and find the id or xpath or css of the drop down box and use it for selecting the desired value. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your help css=input.select2-input.select2-focused ; xpath=(//input[@type='text'])[3]  ; id = roleSpecification_industries_id ; i tried using each of them but no joy command = click; Target - id=roleSpecification_industries_id ; value - label = Accounting

Answer (score 0):

From [Selenium Reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html).

> **storeVisible ( locator, variableName )**
>
> Determines if the specified
>   element is visible. An element can be rendered invisible by setting
>   the CSS "visibility" property to "hidden", or the "display" property
>   to "none", either for the element itself or one if its ancestors. This
>   method will fail if the element is not present.
>
> **Arguments:**
>
> - locator - an element locator
> - variableName - the name of a variable in which the result is to be stored.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> true if the specified element is visible, false otherwise
>
> **Related Assertions, automatically generated:**
>
> - assertVisible ( locator )
> - assertNotVisible ( locator )
> - verifyVisible (locator )
> - verifyNotVisible ( locator )
> - waitForVisible ( locator )
> - waitForNotVisible ( locator )

You can use `verifyVisible(css=input[name="roleSpecification.industries.id"])`

Comment: Thanks for your response i have gone thru the above document but i am wondering why select command for input type hidden is not working. the above document checks only for verifying and asserting it. thanks